# A Riddle of Considerable Magnitude

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I am a quite enormous space
>   And ten of me's the farthest place.
>   Two of those may place the bait
>   And ten times more stands tall and straight.

The answer is a single English word.

Comment: Looks like some IATA code hidden in there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are ...

> ... **vast**.

The magnitudes in the riddle ...

> ... refer to Roman numerals. Each line describes a word that is obtained by taking the Roman digit value of the previous word's first letter and applying the multiplication to that letter. The last value must be 200 times the first value, which can only work by going from V to M via L and C.

*I am a quite enormous space*

> 5 = **V**: A **vast** space is immense.

*And ten of me's the farthest place.*

> 10 × V = **L**: The **last** thing comes after everything else.

*Two of those may place the bait*

> 2 × L = **C**: anglers **cast** their lines to set the bait.

*And ten times more stands tall and straight.*

> 10 × C = **M**: A **mast** is a tall, upright structure.