# A Riddle at the Frontier

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am a quite enormous key,
>   To a mystery you'll never see.
>   If many of me left eyeless bait,
>   Then I am lower, long and straight.

What am I?

Comment: Inspired by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52397/5373), though the answer is (presumably) completely different.

Comment: 'bait' and 'straight' reused! Dupe! *frantically flags* /s

Comment: how do you know the answer is different if you haven't posted the answer to Hugh's question? :). It would be awesome to have the same answer.

Comment: @Marius If I posted my answer on Hugh's, then this one would be spoiled :-) I spent a long time trying to make [answer to mine] fit Hugh's and couldn't make it work - hence this riddle.

Comment: "Long time" - There's a 29 minute difference between the post times :P

Comment: @n_palum On a good day I can solve a riddle in 40 seconds. 29 minutes is an eternity.

Comment: My perverted spirit continues to whisper a certain word to me even if I think that's not the answer :/

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt appears to be stuck on 'lower, long, and straight`lol

Comment: @Forklift, i also have an explanation for the two first lines!

Comment: At the risk of posting too chatty a comment, that's hilarious.

Comment: Wow. I'm blushing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

is the answer:

> space

I am a quite enormous key,

> largest key on the keyboard

To a mystery you'll never see.

> you can't actually see a space, a space is blank or the absence of something

If many of me left eyeless bait,

> tab is a bunch of spaces. Eyeless = "i"-less, so bait => bat, left = leftwards which translates bat to tab (ty [MrGrj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52398/a-riddle-at-the-frontier/52400?noredirect=1#comment160519_52400) and [Hugh](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52398/a-riddle-at-the-frontier/52400?noredirect=1#comment160590_52400))

Then I am lower, long and straight.

> longest lowest straight (hopefully all your keys are straight) key on the keyboard

title

> a play on the word frontier, the space frontier, final frontier (ty [Forklift](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52398/a-riddle-at-the-frontier#comment160480_52400))

Comment: Bingo, you got it! :-D But I intended a slightly different interpretation for line 2, and you still need to solve line 3. Also, what about the title?

Comment: Line 3 : There is no icon on the space bar ?

Comment: Line 3 has a much more precise interpretation.

Comment: Title is likely Star Trekkian in nature.

Comment: You've got pretty much all of it now except line 3. Hint: think wordplay.

Comment: @randal'thor the only thing i can think of is eyeless = i-less for the word bait that would make bat resulting in the phrase: "if many of me left bat" which i have no idea what to do with lol

Comment: @indubitablee Getting closer!

Comment: eyeless bait = bat, which is clearly a reference to Space Bat: http://www.space.com/6442-bat-hung-ride-space.html

Comment: Bat = tab (reversed) :-D

Comment: It's probably not "space bat" (what?), and more likely refers to how the space key does not need dots on a Braille keyboard (eyeless = blind) because of its recognizably long shape.

Comment: maybe because we dont know the actuall lenght of space, we will never see it (line 3)

Comment: I believe the third line is like a cryptic clue. As others have said: "eyeless bait" = "bat". "Left" can mean "read left to right" so "left bat" = "tab". A tab is like many spaces in a row (especially in a fixed font).

Comment: @HughMeyers, would you kindly explain why left bat = tab? wouldnt reading left to right be reading normally so all the letters are in their original orientation? (sorry for the stupid question: i'm totally confused)

Comment: @indubitablee Oops! Sorry. I am somewhat dyslexic. You read it *leftwards* going from right to *left* if that's clearer.

Comment: @HughMeyers ohhhh thanks i understand now tyvm!